# Python Wunderground raw_input data

Tags: python, loops, input, raw-input

I am trying to get the program to ask the user for the airport code and the year (CAN BE ANYTHING - it does not have to be right or anything specific. My professor just wants it to ask and then print the data.)
Here is the code I have:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Create / open a file called wunderdata.txt which will be a CSVfile
f = open('wunderdata.txt', 'w')

# Iterate through months and day
for m in range(1, 13):
    for d in range(1,32):
        # Check if already processed all days in the month
        if (m == 2 and d> 28):
            break
        elif (m in[4, 6, 9, 11] and d > 30):
            break

    # Open wunderground.com url
    airport = str(raw_input("Enter airport code: "))
    year = str(raw_input("Enter year: "))

    timestamp = '2009' + str(m) + str(d)
    print ("Getting data for ") + timestamp

    url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/" + airport + "/" + year + "/" + str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/DailyHistory.html?"
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)     

    # Get temperature from page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")


    #the following two lines are the original (textbook) and first attempt to fix
    # dayTemp = soup.body.wx-value.b.string
    dayTemp = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"wx-value"})[6].get_text()
    seaLevel = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"wx-value"})[16].get_text()      



    # Format month for timestamp
    if len(str(m)) < 2:
        mStamp = '0' + str(m)
    else:
        mStamp = str(m)

    # Format day for timestamp
    if len(str(d)) < 2:
        dStamp = '0' + str(d)
    else:
        dStamp = str(d)

    # Build timestamp
    #timestamp = '2009' + mStamp + dStamp

    # Write timestamp and temperature to file
    f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + " " + "Sea Level Pressure: " + seaLevel + '\n')

# Done getting data! Close file.
f.close()
```

Anyways, this is what comes up when entered:

```
python get-weather-data.py
Enter airport code: KBUF
Enter year: 2009
Getting data for 200911
Enter airport code: KBUF
Enter year: 2009
Getting data for 200912
Enter airport code: KBUF
Enter year: 2009
Getting data for 200913
```

And I want it to be

```
python get-weather-data.py
Enter airport code: KBUF
Enter year: 2009
Getting data for 200911
Getting data for 200912
Getting data for 200913
```

Someone help! I am a beginner so I don't know much about python but would very much appreciate help :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're asking for input *inside* the loop. So, you're asking for input each time it passes through that code.

If you only want to get input once, put it outside the loop. Consider:

```
airport = str(raw_input("Enter airport code: "))
year = str(raw_input("Enter year: "))

for m in range(1, 13):
    for d in range(1,32):
        # Check if already processed all days in the month
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question title is a bit misleading, since the average user doesn't know what "wunderdata" is. And your problem also has nothing to do with this.

From what I understand regarding your question, it's as simple as putting your `raw_input` statements's outside the `for` loops:

```
# Create / open a file called wunderdata.txt which will be a CSVfile
f = open('wunderdata.txt', 'w')

# Enter necessary data
airport = str(raw_input("Enter airport code: "))
year = str(raw_input("Enter year: "))

# Iterate through months and day
for m in range(1, 13):
    ...
```

I believe `raw_input` already returns a string, so the conversion won't be necessary, however, I'm not entirely sure of this since I'm using python 3.x